# Make relative component respect boundary box of grand-...-grandparent component

Tags: html, css, css-position, overflow

I have a table header (of dynamic width) with an element above pointing to it and giving it emphasis. This positioning is implemented using an absolute div inside an absolute div inside a relative div. (Maybe there is a simpler way, I don't know.)

[image]

On smaller screens the emphasis element is clipped by the body's border.

[image]

Is there a way I could force the emphasis element to respect the boundaries of the grand-grand-...-grandparent (the body) instead of overflowing?

Comment: You forgot to show the code

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not so elegant but simple solution would be a media-query with:

```
.emphasis-div {
    width: 200px;
    right: 220px;
}
```

And then adjust font-size etc. to fit the text inside the div.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a media query to define CSS rules based on different screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

My colleague just hit me with a solution: use `translateX(50%)` to perform the centering, and override it with `translateX(0)` based on a media query. The snippet below doesn't demonstrate this behavior (does Stack Overflow snippets support media queries?) but it should work.

```css
table {
  margin-top: 100px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}

.arrangement-container {
  position: relative;
}

.arrangement {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translateX(50%);
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    right: 0;
    transform: none;
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <th>Stuff</th>
  <th>
    <div class="arrangement-container">
      <div class="arrangement">Lorem ipsum</div>
      Stuff
    </div>
  </th>
</table>
```